# Assigning Query Resulting Array to Variables Generated in a For Loop

Tags: powershell

I need to query twice a database and fill the table results into variables:
$1_resultsDataTable and $2_resultsDataTable

Expecting the Write-Host to return the query results versus:
New-Object System.Data.DataTable
New-Object System.Data.DataTable

#query the database twice and load the results into the 2 variables accordingly

```
$prefixes = @(
    '1',
    '2'
)
$count = 0
foreach ($prefix in $prefixes) {
    $count++
    New-Variable -Name "$($prefix)_resultsDataTable" -Value 'New-Object System.Data.DataTable' -Force
}
foreach ($prefix in $prefixes) {
   # Write-Host "Variable '$((Get-Variable -Name "$($prefix)_resultsDataTable").Name)' have a value of 
$((Get-Variable -Name "$($prefix)_resultsDataTable").Value)"
    Set-Variable -Name '$((Get-Variable -Name "$($prefix)_resultsDataTable").Name)' -Value 'ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery' 
    Write-Host $((Get-Variable -Name "$($prefix)_resultsDataTable").Value)
    Start-Sleep 5
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Write-host` cmdlet is great for writing to the host, but it does a lot of formatting to objects and sometimes just renders the type name, which is what's happening here.

If you want to display a `DataTable` to the screen, just output the variable name instead, like this:

```
 ###Creating a new DataTable###
$tempTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
   
##Creating Columns for DataTable##
$col1 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“ColumnName1”)
$col2 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“ColumnName2”)
$col3 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“ColumnName3”)
           
###Adding Columns for DataTable###
$tempTable.columns.Add($col1)
$tempTable.columns.Add($col2)
$tempTable.columns.Add($col3)

    

$row = $tempTable.NewRow()
$row[“ColumnName1”] = “RandomStringData1”
$row[“ColumnName2”] = “RandomStringData2”
$row[“ColumnName3”] = "RandomStringData3"
$tempTable.rows.Add($row)

#does not work
>write-host $tempTable
System.Data.DataRow

#works great!
>$tempTable

ColumnName1       ColumnName2       ColumnName3      
-----------       -----------       -----------      
RandomStringData1 RandomStringData2 RandomStringData3
```